# How to paste yanked text to vim command-line?

Tags: vim, freebsd

Hi is there any way I can paste the yanked text from a vim buffer to a vim command line, as I need to search for some file names which appear in current open text and I have to manually type the file name after :e

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes you can use **<kbd>ctrl+r</kbd>** + <kbd>**"**</kbd> and 
can see this as a reference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906535/how-to-copy-yanked-text-to-vi-command-prompt

Answer (score 7):

You can do `<C-r>"` to paste from the default register or `<C-r>a` to paste from register a.

Answer (score 5):

If your cursor is on the filename before you go to command mode use <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-f</kbd>.

You could also use the command-line window for this, and then edit the command line like you would in the file buffer.

See `:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-F` and `:help command-line-window` for more.

Comment: This is the TAO.

Answer (score 2):

If you type `q:`, you will bring up your command-line history; this can be edited with conventional vim commands, including `p`.

I find accessing this history very useful, so I have the following three lines in my vimrc:

```
" Switch ; and : in normal and visual modes
noremap ; :
noremap : ;
noremap q; q:
cnoremap ;; <c-f>
```

The last one is the most useful -- with it you can either use `q;` or `;;;` to access the command line history; and if you've already started typing a command then you can quickly hit `;;` and gain access to your familiar vim keys. I find this easier than memorising a bunch of key chords (if I wanted that, I'd be using emacs).

Answer (score 0):

`<C-r>+` if you want to paste from system clipboard.